# Correct Mean Squared Error Function for Neural Network Output

Tags: calculus, vectors, machine-learning, error-propagation, mean-square-error

Any help is appreciated.
I would like to know if i missed something, or if that would be correct?

- $m$ is the number of training examples
- $L$ is the Loss-Function
- $\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{(i)}$ is the output vector for training example $i$
- $\mathbf{y}^{(i)}$ is the target vector for training example $i$
- I used the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ to simplify the derivative

$$
 E
=
 \frac{1}{2m}
 \sum_{i=1}^{m}
 L^{(i)}
=
 \frac{1}{2m}
 \sum_{i=1}^{m}
 \frac{1}{2} 
 \| 
  \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{(i)} - \mathbf{y}^{(i)}
 \|^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of simplifying derivative, it suffices to let

$$E = \frac1{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m \|\hat{y}^{(i)} - y^{(i)}\|^2$$

though for the purpose of minimization, they are equivalent as they differ by a positive scalar multiplication.